# NotesXspDocument.save() not allowed to access or modify file "/local/notesdata/xsppers"

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

We have this error message in our xpages application when saving a ticket with an attachment.

It is basically, fileUpload1 bound to a document field (document1) and Button with document1.save();

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=11: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesXspDocument.save() ***not allowed to access or modify file: /local/notesdata/xsppers***/166/08CABEF7AE5340E0DF9C8D46CF56B3B917EA65C6
not allowed to access or modify file: /local/notesdata/xsppers/166/08CABEF7AE5340E0DF9C8D46CF56B3B917EA65C6

The error says not allowed to access or modify the file within /local/notesdata/xsppers.

My question is how to get access to that folder in the server? What to change or do in the security settings on the server for the /xsppers/ folder.

Or a workaround for this issue. By the way I do not have access to the server. Please help thank you

I saw a related question/issue but I am unable to put a comment as I am new - that is why I posted a new question.. Sorry for that

Comment: Hi Rafael, welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like a Linux permission issue that you need someone with access to the Linux server to solve.

Comment: Hi Per, thank you!  The thing is it was working fine until I updated something in one of the custom controls and now that custom control is signed under my name. The other person who signed the custom control left. After that we get this error if there is an attachment when creating a document/ticket.  But I will try to ask the linux team... Thanks again

Comment: I don't think that there is a relation between your code change and the file system level error. You could sign the database with the server id and see if that helps. You can also try a restart of the Domino server and see if that has any impact on the file system level error.